# Optimal way in data.table to make multiple columns from vectors of column name strings

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently experimenting with data.table and looking for the 'optimal' way to to do things.

What I want to do in the following example is have a string with column names, append ".d" for normal deltas and append ".dP" for percentage deltas. (Bear in mind that the columns in the string are only a subset and not the full data.table even though my example is limited to these.)

I want the code to be as compact and fast as possible, using as much of the benefits of both R and data.table.

The solution that I have currently come up with is this:

```
percentDelta<-function(newvalue,basevalue){
  return((newvalue-basevalue)/basevalue)
}

normalDelta<-function(newvalue,basevalue){
  return(newvalue-basevalue)
}

DT = data.table(price=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8), otherMetric=c(3,4,5,1,3,4,5))
deltaColsNames = c("otherMetric")
deltaColsNewNames <- paste0(deltaColsNames,'.d')
percentColsNewNames <- paste0(deltaColsNames,'.dP')

DT[,eval(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,eval(deltaColsNames),with=F],normalDelta,price)]
DT[,eval(percentColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,eval(deltaColsNames),with=F],percentDelta,price)]
```

I am not quite sure if the data.table calls to generate multiple columns is correct there? Is using "lapply" with "eval" the way one would go about this?

EDIT: Should I avoid the use of "with=F"?

```
DT[,eval(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,which(names(DT) %in% deltaColsNames)],normalDelta,price)]
DT[,eval(percentColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,which(names(DT) %in% deltaColsNames)],percentDelta,price)]
```

Comment: You can avoid calling `DT` within `DT` rather use `.SD` and combine it with `mget`. For instance `DT[, (percentColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD[, mget(deltaColsNames)], percentDelta, price)]`

Comment: The expression you proposed returns an:
Error: value for 'otherMetric' not found

I might be reading the mget wrong, but it is not passing the object from the actual data.table?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Also tested on multiple columns as an input. Does this returns an error? `DT = data.table(price=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8), otherMetric=c(3,4,5,1,3,4,5), otherMetric2=c(3,4,5,1,3,4,5)) ; percentColsNewNames <- paste0(deltaColsNames,'.dP') ; DT[, (percentColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD[, mget(deltaColsNames)], percentDelta, price)]`

Comment: swapping the "mget()" for "eval()" and adding with=F made it run, but it is now quite a bit slower on a significant dataset than my originally proposed solution.

And yes, your code snippet produces the same error. Bear in mind I am on version 1.9.5 from the data.table github and not the one on CRAN

Comment: It couldn't work unless you added `with = FALSE` too. Did you try running `mget` **without** adding `with = FALSE`? I'm also using v 1.9.5 btw.

Comment: Yes, I copy pasted your snippet word per word.
And yes, i did add with=F to make the eval work.

R version 3.2.0?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `deltaColsNames <- c("otherMetric", "otherMetric2")` too there.

Comment: Also, something like `DT[, (percentColsNewNames) := as.data.table(mapply(percentDelta, .SD, DT[, .(price)])), .SDcols = deltaColsNames]` could work (not sure regarding speed).

Comment: I reinstalled the 1.9.5 version from github, now your code snippet works! :)
That last piece of code is horrendously slow btw, I'll put up a speed comparison as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is solved now with [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/68091d851d400b4d768f3c41c0210da76945c12b), we can now do this just fine:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD, normalDelta, price), .SDcols=deltaColsNames]
```

Answer (score 2):

So for answering the question and adding the optimisations from the comments, the following answers arose:

```
require(data.table) #version 1.9.5 from github needed!

normalDelta<-function(newvalue,basevalue){
  return(newvalue-basevalue)
}

DT = data.table(price=rep(c(3,4,5),each=200000000), otherMetric=sample(c(1,3,6),200000000,T))
deltaColsNames = c("otherMetric")
deltaColsNewNames <- paste0(deltaColsNames,'.d')
```

Scenario 1, using "eval" and "with=F":

```
system.time(DT[,(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,eval(deltaColsNames),with=F],normalDelta,price)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#2.134   1.747   3.880
```

Scenario 2, using "which(names) %in%" to avoid strings as column indexes:

```
system.time(DT[,(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(DT[,which(names(DT) %in% deltaColsNames)],normalDelta,price)])
#user  system elapsed 
#1.652   1.105   2.756
```

Scenario 3, using ".SD" syntax and eval() in 1.9.5 (in 1.9.4, this was slower):

```
system.time(DT[,(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD[, eval(deltaColsNames),with=F], normalDelta, price)])
 #user  system elapsed
#2.148   1.847   4.764
```

Scenario 4, using ".SD" syntax and which() in 1.9.5 (in 1.9.4, this was also slower):

```
system.time(DT[,(deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD[, which(names(DT) %in% deltaColsNames)], normalDelta, price)])
#user  system elapsed 
#1.701   1.117   2.817
```

Scenario 5, using mget():

```
system.time(DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(mget(deltaColsNames), normalDelta, price)])
#user  system elapsed 
#1.426   1.166   2.591
```

Scenario 6: mget and .SD combined:

```
system.time(DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD[, mget(deltaColsNames)], normalDelta, price)])
#user  system elapsed 
#2.149   1.788   4.974
```

**UPDATE: After increasing the size of the dataset: 
Scenario 2&4&5 are coming out quite ahead.
However, scenario 5 has a much higher memory footprint than 2&4, as I ran into memory issues on my laptop when testing this with a bigger dataset
(see updated results above)**

Comment: Why not simply `DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(mget(deltaColsNames), normalDelta, price)]`?

Comment: well, I wasn't familiar with the mget yet, now I am and updated my answer accordingly. 
Thanks for the addition and suggestion! definitely the fastest one yet.

Comment: I don't see big differences here, maybe worth benchmarking on a bigger data set

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the test on a 600million row dataset.
Weirdly, the "simplest" looking option with just 'mget' has fallen behind the .SD solution by quite a bit. 
The solution with calling DT inside of DT is only marginally slower than the .SD solution, but still faster than straight up using 'mget'.

Comment: It would seem that memory issues skewed my results, I toned the number of rows down to 300 million and now the results seem to match intuition more.

However, this would imply that everything that employs mget has a much higher memory footprint than the other solutions and I am not quite sure what I would prefer then..

Comment: The fact that `mget` is less typing doesn't mean it's more efficient.

Comment: Anyway, I think the best solution will be `DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD, normalDelta, price), .SDcols = deltaColsNames]` but this is currently doesn't work due to a bug that we are waiting to be fixed.

Comment: `system.time(DT[, (deltaColsNewNames) := lapply(.SD, normalDelta, DT$price), .SDcols = deltaColsNames])`
runs in 2.517s already, so I'm guessing you're right.