# Specifying data.table column(s) with strings

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following minimal working example:

```r
library(magrittr) # for the %>% pipe 
library(data.table) 

# test data.table contains common_column and two others
test_dt <- data.table(test_column_one = c(1, 2, 3), test_column_two = c("x","y","z"), common_column = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3") ) 

# some other data.table that contains common_column
other_dt <- data.table( additional_info = c("US", "US", "GB"), common_column = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")) 

example_function <- function(dt_column){
  # does some things on the data tables based on the column parameter passed
  merged_dt <- merge(other_dt, test_dt[,.(common_column, dt_column)], by = "common_column")[order(dt_column),] # order by the dt_column
  return(merged_dt)
} 

# calling the example function
example_function(test_dt$test_column_one)
```

How can I modify the code to:

1. be able to specify a string with the column name as argument instead
2. be able to pass a vector or list of strings with column names

I want to avoid for-loops and take advantage of optimized data.table syntax where possible.

I tried working with `unlist()` as well as with `..` syntax specific to data.table, but somehow I always got weird error messages and am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: There is no need for pipe, try `... by = "common_column")[order(dt_column),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Create a vector of column names

There are three ways to do this which I set out below, but I think the clearest is to create a vector of columns to use with the `..` syntax.

```r
example_function <- function(dt_column, dt1 = other_dt, dt2 = test_dt) {
    cols_to_merge <- c("common_column", dt_column)
    merged_dt <- merge(
        dt1,
        dt2[, ..cols_to_merge],
        by = "common_column"
    )

    # No need to pipe - see explanation below
    setorderv(merged_dt, dt_column)
    return(merged_dt)
}

example_function("test_column_one")
#    common_column additional_info test_column_one
#           <char>          <char>           <num>
# 1:           ID1              US               1
# 2:           ID2              US               2
# 3:           ID3              GB               3
```

#### Comparison with other approaches

Let's assume that we want to select `mpg` and one dynamic column from `mtcars`, which in this case happens to be `wt`.

```r
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
col_of_interest <- "wt"
```

I think there are basically three `data.table` approaches.

1. As above. As the [data.table v1.10.2 (31 Jan 2017) docs](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.1.md#datatable-v1102--31-jan-2017) state:

> When `j` is a symbol prefixed with `..` it will be looked up in calling scope and its value taken to be column names or numbers.

```r
cols  <- c("mpg", col_of_interest)
mtcars[, ..cols]
```

2. Since [data.table v1.11.0 (01 May 2018)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.1.md#datatable-v1110--01-may-2018):

> this [the `..`] prefix is now expanded to all symbols appearing in `j=`

```r
mtcars[, c("mpg", ..col_of_interest)]
```

3. As set out in the [Using .SD for Data Analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html) vignette.

```r
cols <- c("mpg", col_of_interest)
mtcars[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]
```

Personally I think creating a vector of column names is the clearest approach, but the second method means one fewer variable created. The third approach is the most backwards compatible.

#### A note on using `order()`

The docs specify that `..` only works in `j`. The following statements are equivalent:

```r
mtcars[order(mpg)]
mtcars[order(mpg),]
mtcars[i = order(mpg),]
```

As `order(mpg)` is the argument provided to `i`, if we set `x  <- "mpg"`, it is not valid to do `mtcars[order(..x)]`.

If you must use `order()`, here are some ways you could do it:

```r
# Use ..
mtcars[order(mtcars[, ..x])]
# Use `[[`
mtcars[order(mtcars[[x]])]
# Use .SD
mtcars[mtcars[, sapply(.SD, order), .SDcols = x]]
# Use get() (this has been retired in favour of `env` - see comments)
mtcars[order(get(x))]
```

However, these create a copy of the data, they are not beautiful and they are also limited (what if you want to order by two columns?).

It is generally preferable, as in the `example_function()` I provided above, rather than creating a copy by piping and subsetting, to take advantage of the `data.table` efficiency by using [`setorderv()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.10/topics/setorder) to modify in place:

```r
setorderv(mtcars, x)
```

This is also easily extended to cases where you want to order by more than one column.

Comment: Although this is a very nice answer, these interfaces (including others not mentioned, such as `mget` and `with=F`) are considered retired or at least will be imminently. The new standard for programming on `data.table` uses `env`, which works across `i`, `j`, and `by` in a clean and consistent way.

Comment: @Tobo thanks - I've added `get()` and good point about `env`. When you say these interfaces are considered retired, are you referring to the methods for referencing a variable in `i` or `j`? `env` seems to be a better approach to any of the methods for `i`. In terms of `j`, I had a sense that `with = FALSE` had been, but `..` is relatively new and cleaner than `env`. I looked at the link in your answer and I can see `get()` and `eval()` are being retired, but I didn't spot anything about `..`.

Comment: Hi @SamR - the question is about a general method of defining variables programmatically, which is explicitly what the new `env` is finally designed to address. `..` (2018) allowed substitution in j, but `env` (2023) now gives a general interface for doing everything across all three arguments. The vignette gives `get`, `mget` and `eval` as _examples_ of the kind of injection/substitution methods that can now be retired, and of course nothing is being removed or somehow banned.

Comment: Looking at your example, we want to arrive at `mtcars[order(wt), .(mpg, wt)]` where `wt` is defined programmatically. After `some_col <- wt`, one way of achieving the same result as you say is `cols <- c("mpg", some_col); setorderv(mtcars[, ..cols], some_col)`. But `env` now lets us do `mtcars[order(v), .(mpg, v), env = list(v = some_col)]` directly. Since `env` is general, it would be mixing idioms to do `mtcars[order(v), ..cols, env = list(v = some_col)]` (but it works). On the other hand if all we needed to do was substitute inside j then sure, why not just keep using `..`.

Comment: get, mget, eval (not sure about ..var) could possibly result in slower code comparing to use of new env var, as they may suppress some code optimizations. Env was designed to bypass all that by doing substitution at the very beginning, resulting substituted code to be like written by an user, so to benefit all possible optimizations in DT.

Comment: @jangorecki thanks that is helpful and interesting. Do you have a link to anywhere explaining this in more detail, or somewhere in the source where these type of optimisations are done? I'm not sure I really what kind optimisation you're talking about.

Comment: `v="a"; dt[verbose=TRUE,, lapply(mget(v), sum), grp]` will not get GForce optimized `gsum`. there are many already resolved issues from the past around those interfaces, list of still open ones is https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5886

Comment: See also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32092228/2490497

Comment: @jangorecki thanks this is interesting. So in the case of `order()`, `data.table` applies `forder()` whether you use `x <- "wt"; mtcars[verbose = TRUE, order(x), env = list(x = "wt")]` or `mtcars[verbose = TRUE, order(get(x))]`? But in the case of `mtcars[verbose = TRUE, , lapply(mget(x), sum), gear]`, we don't get `gsum()`, whereas we do with `mtcars[verbose = TRUE, , lapply(.SD, sum), gear, .SDcols = x]`. I'd like to add this to the answer and compare to the other approaches - but I'm not sure what the equivalent of the `lapply()` statement is using `..` or `env` is. Do you know?

Comment: `mtcars[verbose = TRUE, , j, gear, env=list(j=lapply("wt", function(x) call("sum", as.name(x))))]` it will get much simpler after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5032 then `j = lapply(x, sum), env=list(x=as.list("wt"))`

Comment: @jangorecki thanks! So the impression I'm getting is that for use in `i`, `env` seems like a game-changer, but it doesn't seem to have performance or significant syntax advantages over `.SD` in `j`. Does that seem like a fair assessment to you as one of the `data.table` devs?

Comment: .SD is very simple use case. In new programming vignette you will find much more use cases for env. Yes it is something that I as DT dev could work on, but as we are volunteers, and there are many other things there that eats a lot of time, therefore this particular issue may not be addressed so fast.

Answer (score 5):

The new `env` **interface for programming on data.table** solves all these issues and makes other methods and hacks unnecessary.

Using SamR's nice example of selecting "mpg" and `some_col` from mt_cars (in j), while also ordering on `some_col` (in i):

```
setDT(mtcars)
some_col <- "wt"
mtcars[order(v), .(mpg, v), env=list(v=some_col)]
```

See News item 10 [here](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html) and [this vignette](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html). To update to development version 1.14.99: `data.table::update_dev_pkg()`.

Comment: Coming to CRAN hopefully within couple days!

Comment: Once this is implemented, when should I use .. and when should I use env? Is any more performant than the other?