# get(x) does not work in R data.table when using paste0 function

Tags: r, data.table

Currently I am struggle with the get function in R data table. Specially, I was trying the  function conTMLE [here](https://github.com/helenecharlotte/Web-appendix-continuous-time-TMLE#changing-the-sample-size-n):

Whenever I run this function, the R will return the error message like:
"Error in get(paste0("int.A", k)) : first argument has length > 1".
I find it is caused by here

```
dt[, (paste0("W", k+1)):=(get(paste0("int.A", k)))/(get(paste0("fit.A", k)))]
```

Here k is in a loop, I have tried some methods, like add as.character. I also tried defining j = k in each loop, but it caused more problems, like " eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'j' not found".

Currently, I am thinking about add .. in front of the strings. However, I tried "(get(..paste0("int.A", k)))" as "(get(paste0("..","int.A", k)))". They all do not work.

I wonder how to fix this problem! Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: the error is telling you the problem -- length(k)>1. without reproducible code we can't debug for you further.

Comment: Please provide sample data, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: BTW, `get(c("a","b"))` is what is generating the error, it has nothing to do with [tag:data.table].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(EDIT: a proper answer)**

The claim in the question title is not actually true. It's just that `get()` takes a single argument and you evidently have a k in your code that is of longer length:

```
# reprex of the original error
get(c("foo", "bar"))
Error in get(c("foo", "bar")) : first argument has length > 1
```

As for solving the requirement, you say that "k is in a loop", which I think means k is a scalar looping over columns, but it's possible you really do intend k of length > 1.

*Either way*, you can avoid `get()` (and the loop over columns if that is what it is) by passing k as a vector and doing a multiple assignment.

```
k <- 1:2
```

You *could* actually use `mget()`, and since it returns a list you need to convert the results to objects that you can divide, e.g.:

```
# mget()    
dt[, paste0("W", k+1) := dt[, mget(paste0("int.A", k))] / dt[, mget(paste0("fit.A", k))]]
```

But you *can and should* avoid using `get`/`mget` and inject the variable names using `.SDcols` instead:

```
# .SDcols (better)
dt[, paste0("W", k+1) := dt[, .SD, .SDcols=paste0("int.A", k)] / dt[, .SD, .SDcols=paste0("fit.A", k)] ]
```

Also worth advertising that as of the recent v1.15 **use of `get()` and `mget()` (in use cases that `.SD` can't handle) is discouraged in favour of the new `env()` interface** given to us by the `data.table` team  - see the links and discussions around [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760559/specifying-data-table-columns-with-strings) question. That said, `.SD` is fine in this particular case.

---

(**First "answer":**)

As @r2evans points out, you need to provide a reproducible example. The code below shows that your problem is not reproducible, because your line of code works on the face of it. Therefore, as @MichaelChirico points out, the problem lies elsewhere.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(int.A1 = c(50,60), int.A2 = c(120,8), fit.A1 = c(1,3), fit.A2 = c(2,4))
for (k in 1:2) {
  dt[, (paste0("W", k+1)):=(get(paste0("int.A", k)))/(get(paste0("fit.A", k)))]
}
dt
> dt
   int.A1 int.A2 fit.A1 fit.A2    W2    W3
    <num>  <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num>
1:     50    120      1      2    50    60
2:     60      8      3      4    20     2
```

Comment: Ahh, but OP did not use a `for` loop. If you start instead with `k <- 1:2` and drop the `for` loop then this fails, suggesting that `k` is an external variable of length 2 or greater. So ... I would suggest that your `for` loop might be the fix for the OP's issue, though we won't know for certain without more info. Time will tell :-)

Comment: Well, OP does say "k is in a loop", which I assumed meant scalar k looping over columns., but yes it's possible they mean a vector. Anyway, I think the answer in either case is .SD with a multiple assignment and have put this up as a proper answer, though you and @MichaelChirico might well have improvements.

Comment: I guess I skipped that in my reading, mea culpa. Hope this works for the OP!

Comment: Thank all of you! It works. As the function "conTMLE" has 1000 lines, a lot of places have this problem. It takes me much time to fix all of them, and it works now! I so appreciate your generous help!